# Find Embedded Document ID

Tags: mongodb

Regarding to my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882292/sort-and-limit-embedded-document-mongodb), with the same collection schema (i should've rewrite it here)

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c64e4dd0a36b93c7deafa"), 
    "name" : "Asd", 
    "email" : "asd@neurondigital.tech", 
    "password" : "$2b$12$66OTK8mSWELMF5YiF9HMUuHEeOVLI61aINjWs1Cmn1699lLJfz/7y", 
    "auto_ml" : true, 
    "notification" : true, 
    "photo" : null, 
    "tariff_id" : null, 
    "city" : null, 
    "sub_district" : null, 
    "village" : null, 
    "latitude" : null, 
    "longitude" : null, 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-13T20:43:00.871+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-13T23:08:26.149+0000"), 
    "family_members" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c98446f0321f6986755d8"), 
            "name" : "Asd Jr.", 
            "email" : "asd.jr@neurondigital.tech", 
            "password" : "$2b$12$K83ScPPb19dtELJs4tc0He9NffE4f9pr9cvjcnpyNoeAUh60cmQXq", 
            "auto_ml" : true, 
            "notification" : true, 
            "photo" : null, 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:22:12.249+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:22:12.249+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c984b6f0321f6986755d9"), 
            "name" : "Asd Grand Jr.", 
            "email" : "asd.grandjr@neurondigital.tech", 
            "password" : "$2b$12$UXfEUGhHf4Hli9oaViirJut.xWAoIWqac6xEdREJKfXq0OVSdGogu", 
            "auto_ml" : true, 
            "notification" : true, 
            "photo" : null, 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:22:19.270+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:22:19.270+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "rooms" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c98826f0321f6986755da"), 
            "name" : "Ruang Makan", 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:14.839+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:14.840+0000"), 
            "devices" : [

            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c98846f0321f6986755db"), 
            "name" : "Kamar Mandi", 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:16.823+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:16.823+0000"), 
            "devices" : [

            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c98866f0321f6986755dc"), 
            "name" : "Kamar Tidur Utama", 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:18.310+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:18.310+0000"), 
            "devices" : [

            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c98876f0321f6986755dd"), 
            "name" : "Ruang Tamu", 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:19.693+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:19.693+0000"), 
            "devices" : [

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find rooms that match with `_id` and `rooms._id`. I'm running this query but the result is not as i expected:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { $and: [
        {"_id": ObjectId("5f0c64e4dd0a36b93c7deafa")}, 
        {"rooms._id": ObjectId("5f0c98846f0321f6986755db")}
    ] }
  },
  {
    $project: { rooms: 1 }
  },
  { $unwind: "$rooms" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      rooms: { $first: "$rooms" }
    }
  }
])
```

The problem seems on the accumulator expression, whereas i use `$first` and the result is showing the first room in the embedded documents. How to find the exact thing as written in `$match`?

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? Once you have done unwind, you can have another $match with the same criteria as before (just with room).

Comment: My expected output is the document of room where has id as written in match, which is the name "Kamar Mandi"

Comment: Instead of an aggregation. you can try using the array [$ (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html) operator.

Comment: @prasad_ do you have any example within my case?

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking the match query, i figured out the way it should be:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
        "_id": ObjectId("5f0c64e4dd0a36b93c7deafa")
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { rooms: 1 }
  },
  { $unwind: "$rooms" },
  {
      $match: {
            "rooms._id": ObjectId("5f0c98846f0321f6986755db")
      }
  }
])
```

There must to be 2 `$match`es, not comparing it with `$and` operator

Comment: I don't think the last `$group` stage is necessary

Comment: @thammada.ts you're right, i edited my answer, thank you :)

Comment: It comes another question, how could i put that query into update criteria on update query? We know that update() needs two argument, i want to put that search result into first argument as a criteria

Comment: You should ask a new question. Feel free to post the link as a comment here

Comment: Nevermind. Found out the solution here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/ :)

Comment: Excuse me, would you mind help me solve this question? Thank you in advance :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927421/lookup-foreignfield-from-nested-array